# Scheme: Updating a globally defined list in another function

Tags: list, scheme, racket

I have looked for many topics in this site but no one has solved my problem. As you can see, I am a newbie to Scheme. I am not used to functional programming so it seems pretty much strange to me. 
What I want to ask is, I have a globally defined list. I want to update this list in a function and display it somewhere else.

```
set! db (append db (list entry))
```

When I use this given code, it returns me `'(#<void>)`
Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! In order to have fast answers, please familiarize yourself on how to pose questions. In particular, note that questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and **the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself**. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: set! Is supposed to return void. Do you mean that db is now '(#<void>)? If so, that means that entery is void.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `cons` to add one element at a time.

```
(define db (list))
(set! db (cons 1 db))
(set! db (cons 2 db))
(set! db (cons 3 db))
db
```